# How to load braintree Drop in Payment UI inside my view in android

Tags: javascript, android, braintree

Is it possible to load braintree Drop in Payment UI inside my view in android

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

If you are creating a native app, then you can follow the instructions posted here in regards to the native Braintree SDK for Android: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/android/v2

If you are specifically talking about a WebView, it can work, however, there are possible limitations, which are listed here:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/browser-support#webviews

Comment: Joseph, the DropIn UI is very slow (takes more than a second to show up)...is there any way to make UX more adaptive, to not force users wait 'for something'...they'll probably leave page faster than results arrive....